# Is Ubuntu's mouse(pointer) weird?

Tags: mouse

I used Ubuntu 10.04 previously and 10.10 now. What i felt is, it's pointer is a bit weird. It does point exactly on the target area but it slightly trembles or shake while the finger is on touchpad.Some of u might have noticed and may be not.Similar is not the case in Windows. I found this case in my friends Ubuntu too. Is this the bug? if yes ,anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your sensitivity is too high. Try opening your Mouse Preferences and lowering your acceleration and sensitivity options.

Answer (score 0):

I experience this too. It is a bug.

You can file a bug report here at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu)

You can also initiate a bug report from within Ubuntu. First open System Monitor and identify what process-ID the bug most likely relates to. I'm not sure which process to use here, so you might guess and indicate it's a guess in the bug-report description. Let's say the process-ID is 1234 for purposes of this example. You would do the following:

```
Alt+F2 
ubuntu-bug 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

I caught one reason for this occasionally happening was that my mouse's wire or some other object was touching my laptop's trackpad. Thus the two separate mouse inputs were colliding with each other and causing the mouse pointer to shake and not respond as well.
Removing the obstruction from the trackpad fixed it.